# How and when do I recruit Tali?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I started playing the first few plot missions in ME3 last night, and very early on I recruited Garrus.  Both he and Tali survived the events of ME2 (on my save), and I believe they are both potential squadmates.  They tended to round out my team in previous installments.

If I've just recruited Garrus, how far am I from recruiting Tali?  If I want to recruit her as fast as possible, what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will be able to recruit Tali on the [Priority: Rannoch](http://www.primagames.com/games/mass-effect-3/primaguides/207/walkthrough/8758) mission.  Which you can't do until after:

> [The citadel attack by Cerberus](http://www.primagames.com/games/mass-effect-3/primaguides/207/walkthrough/8749).

It will be quite a while before you can recruit Tali if you just got Garrus.

Also, take note that you may not be able to recruit her:

> If you do side with the Geth on Rannoch, one of the possible outcomes she'll commit suicide.  If she died in mass effect 2 during the suicide mission, and you imported your save, then she will not appear in mass effect 3.